# PHP how to copy a tab character for pasting

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP page that will pull 2 fields' data from a table and I want to be able to paste 2 fields into 2 text boxes on an external Internet Explorer window (that isn't mine)

Example fields `mydata1`, `mydata2`
Copy those fields as `mydata1` then a tab key to navigate the user to the second textbox and then `mydata2` so that when the user clicks on the first text box on the Internet Explorer window, it pastes in only `mydata1`, and then hits the tab key and in the second text box (arrived at from the tab key), paste only `mydata2`.

This is for a project to help make filling out an external form easier for my users.

I think of it like a "sendkey" in VB?

Comment: I don't quiet get what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: With tab you jump to the next input inside form, and its normal behavior of all major browsers, so where is the problem?

Comment: add the onfocus to the textbox and update the field.

Comment: Lets say there is a web page that isn't mine such as a form asking for your name and birthdate. A user will navigate to my php page, which will pull those 2 values from a table and copy them into the computer's memory (just like a copy paste) but will put a tab key between the 2 copied values so that when the user does an ALT TAB to go to the internet explorer page, and clicks on the first field, it will paste just the first name, hit the tab key and then paste the birthdate in the second field.

Comment: Im copying 2 data fields into copy memory so that the user only has to paste one time, to get mydata1 into the first internet explorer text box, hit tab (from the copied tab), then paste the mydata2 value in the second internet explorer text field.

Comment: The window the user is pasting to isnt my web page. Just the php page that copies the two fields into copy memory belongs to me.

Comment: From further research it seems like I will just have to echo a couple of text boxes on my own php page and then populate 2 text boxes there and allow the user to manually copy from each text box and paste on the other Internet Explorer window.

Comment: Trademark capitalization.

Comment: Trademark capitalization? I don't understand, IKavanaugh. Please explain.

Comment: “it will paste just the first name, hit the tab key and then paste the birthdate in the second field.” You can’t paste keyboard commands like hitting tab to focus the next input on a web page.

Comment: @MartinBean That's what I'm finding as well. Thank you for repling. My only workable solution I've found is to have my php page echo into separate text boxes the fields I want to copy, and then the user can click within the field and copy and then the user can alt tab to the other web page (not owned by me) and paste there, one field at a time.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?